# Diophantine approximation with integer vectors

Tags: real-analysis, approximation, diophantine-approximation

I would like to determine whether or not there exists ${\beta > 0}$ and ${\gamma \geq 2 }$ such that ${ \forall (m_{1},m_{2}) \in \mathbb{Z}^{2} \setminus (0,0) }$, one has the inequality

$$
|m_{1} \!+\! \sqrt{2} \, m_{2}| \geq \frac{\beta}{||(m_{1} , m_{2})||^{\gamma}} \, , 
$$
where ${|| (m_{1} , m_{2}) ||}$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

(I am convinced this should be linked to [Diophantine approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation), but I can't get the details to work... And I may be missing the obvious...)

(Context : This comes from [KAM Theory](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Kolmogorov-Arnold-Moser_theory), for which in order to conserve regular orbits, the frequencies of motions have to satisfy such diophantine inequalities.)

Comment: If $\|\cdot\|$ is any norm, you can try showing this for the Euclidean norm first, then from the equivalence of the norms, the general result would follow.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay Yes exactly. I didn't specified the norm on purpose because in finite dimensions, they are all equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Liouville's theorem on Diophantine approximation, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation), there exists a constant $c$ such that 
$$|\sqrt{2}-{m_1\over m_2}|>{c\over m_2^2}.$$
for every choice of  integers $m_1,m_2$ such that $m_2>0$
Consequently, for every choice of integers such that $m_2>0$:

$$|m_2\sqrt{2}-m_1|>{c\over m_2}\geq {c\over\sqrt{m_2^2+m_1^2}}$$

Since this holds for every integer $m_1$, we can replace $m_1$ by $-m_1$ and deduce that: for all pairs $(m_1,m_2)$ such that $m_2>0$ we have:

$$|m_2\sqrt{2}+m_1|> {c\over\sqrt{m_2^2+m_1^2}}$$

Now if $(m_1,m_2)$ is such that $m_2<0$, use the above for the pair $(-m_1,-m_2)$, so that a-posteriori the inequality holds for all pairs of non-zero integers, and the **Euclidean norm**. As was mentioned above, the result follows now for an arbitrary norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Could you detail where the $2$ comes from in $... >  \frac{c}{m_{2}^{2}}$ ? Is it linked to the fact that $\sqrt{2}$ is solution of the polynom $X^{2}-1=0$, which is of degree 2 ?

Comment: Yes, it is. The power of $m_2$ is the degree of the algebraic number $\sqrt{2}$. For $2^{1/3}$, we'd have to take a power of three, and so on, so en-route we see that we a similar result holds also for $2^{1/3}$, but I am not sure about $2^{1/4}$. You'd probably need the reverse diophantine inequalities.